# Why does my svg file look worse than my png file?

Tags: wordpress

I am going through my image files and replacing them with svg, from png. The problem is that now, when I scale up or zoom in on mobile for example, the images look worse than they did with png.

As I understand, SVG is scalable vector graphics, so you should be able to scale them as big as you like without distortion.

Well, the images have been converted from png to svg so should, in theory, look better, mostly when scaled up.

You can see an example here of png background image at https://adsler.co.uk/jobs and svg here https://adsler.co.uk/dating/

You will see that in jobs (png) the image scales quite high before distortion but in dating (svg) it zooms only a bit before it distorts, whereas it should be the other way around.

So what am I doing wrong and how to fix please? Basically I just want crystal clear images across my site.

On further further inspection, in Chrome this is most definitely the case, but in Firefox, on mobile, it scales quite high before distortion.

Two points then come up.

1. Why is it distorting at all? It should be infinitely scalable.
2. When I  zoom in on an svg in Firefox, does any distortion occur simply because my mobile phone reaches the peak of its display capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that while this image is technically an SVG, the fact that it started as a PNG and was converted has left it as a png image wrapper in an svg, rather than a true vector.

If you open it up in a text editor you can see that the whole content inside the `<svg>` wrapper is an image attribute `<image id="image0" width="2160" height="3840" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="...` etc.

What this means is that it will essentially behave in the same way as a raster image rather than a vector graphic.

I'd advise trying to recreate the graphic as a vector using something like Illustrator, Sketch or Inkscape. Do you have the image saved in anything other than a png format?

Comment: I'll assume your answer is correct. However, when I've done this before using file converters, the png behaves like an svg once converted.

Comment: It's honestly touch and go and depends on both the image and the converter, some image features can't be automatically converted so the svg will end up including just the raster image as a link.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you recommend one that's free, online and accessible from mobile phone?

Comment: Also, why does it look better in Firefox when enlarged in pseudo svg?